# DYLD, Library not loaded: /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCore.dylib

Tags: ios, swift

Termination Description: DYLD, Library not loaded: /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCore.dylib | Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/74906475-64B7-49CD-A0A4-9C522D82CDAD/RiverAppApp.app/Frameworks/SnapKit.framework/SnapKit | Reason: image not found

I use iOS12.1 failed, but iOS 13/14/15 is good. Why?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Set

```
ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES = YES
```

iOS 13+ OK, because Swift Standard libraries becomes ABI stable and became part of iOS